# Resizing window on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a button that will resize the browser window on clicking.From what I've seen this is definitely possible. Using JQuery I have written the following code:

```
$('.resize').click(function(){
window.resizeTo("300px", "300px");
});
```

To affect the following html:

```
<button class="resize">click me</button>
```

But when clicked, the button does nothing. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Based off your comment, the question has changed. My edit:**

You cannot resize the current global `window` object in most modern browsers. You can refer to the following two links on why that is considered bad practice, and possible alternatives (Perhaps opening your application through a popup window to begin with?):

- [Resize the browser with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022787/can-i-resize-the-browser-window)
- [Why is resizing the browser window bad practice? (Popup alternatives here)](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9903/why-is-resizing-the-browser-window-bad-practice/9962#9962)

An alternative that I haven't seen around this topic is to use CSS `@media screen{  }` to detect and implement features based on how big the window is. Try doing some research on [that](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en).

Comment: I pasted the wrong snippet sorry, the class is corresponding correctly! Silly of me. The function itself still doesn't work though :/

Comment: `window.resizeTo` will not work in Chrome or Opera. Firefox also has the option from the user's side to deactivate this function.

Comment: Fair enough. :( 
Do you know is there any other option for this? 
I am creating an interactive application that works best at a certain window size.

Comment: @MarcMurray Check my edits above. You can try displaying a warning to the client when their window is bigger than what you want.