# Resizing Browser Window

Tags: javascript, html, browser, resize

Is there any JS or html script to resize browser window after click on *ahref link*?

**Site1**: Window (750x400px) ---**click** and resize---> **Site2**: Window (full size)

Answer (score 2):

[Can I resize the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022787/can-i-resize-the-browser-window)

From **Sandgol** :

> The resizeTo method is disabled by default in several browsers, and I know that it can also be manually disabled in Firefox.
>   It has been widely misused, so most browser vendors feel that it should be disabled, or at least a user controllable option.