# Is it possible to resize browser window size using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to resize my browser window using Javascript to test my responsive webpage design functionality. 
But I didn't find any option for the same.

What I found is, we can modify window size for newly pop up window as shown below:

```
<body>

<p>Open a new window, and resize the width and height to 500px:</p>

<button onclick="openWin()">Create window</button>
<button onclick="resizeWin()">Resize window</button>

<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=100, height=100");
 }

function resizeWin() {
    myWindow.resizeTo(250, 250);
    myWindow.focus();
}
</script>

</body>
```

I have defined some responsive behaviour using following css code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
     //style changes
}
```

Can we resize browser window where our page is launched? Or it is not possible?

Comment: this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022787/can-i-resize-the-browser-window

Comment: I have already mentioned use of resizeTo() method. which is not useful in my case. :(

Answer (score 0):

You likely can use `resizeBy/resizeTo` but why don't you want to use Chrome built-in tester?
You can open developer console `cmd/ctrl + alt + I` and click on `Device Toolbar` or `cmd/ctrl + shift + M` and adjust screen size using predefined templates or create your own

**Update**

For automation test there are a several ways to adjust it. Which runtime is running your Jasmine tests? For PhantomJS you can use

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 480,
  height: 800
};
```

More info [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html)

Comment: We are using Jasmine framework for testing functionality. In that I have to code window size changes.

Answer (score 0):

To resize the window, you can simply do this:

```
window.resizeTo(width, height);
```

Comment: copy pase http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022787/can-i-resize-the-browser-window

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 options to implement responsive layout structure :

1. by using javascript..

   ```
       function  ResponsiveLayout() {

           if (screen.width <= 1440) {

               $('#content').addClass("pipeline1");

           }
           else if (screen.width > 1440 && screen.width <= 1600) {
               $('#content').addClass("pipeline2");
           }
           else if (screen.width > 1600) {
               $('#content').addClass("pipeline3");
           }
       };ResponsiveLayout()
   ```

By using css3 media query :

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){css attrabutes}
@media (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 981px){css attrabutes}
@media (max-width: 980px) and (min-width: 641px){css attrabutes}
@media (max-width: 640px) and (min-width: 481px){css attrabutes}
@media (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 321px){css attrabutes}
@media (max-width: 320px){css attrabutes}
```

Professionally Media query would be better option but can we use javascript where limited access of css file or inline css -:)

Comment: Author wants to resize **browser window** using js and not make his layout responsive