# Resizing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I want to resize the browser using my javascript or jquery code. I have tried by modifying window.InnerRadius value. Please

```js
function resize() {
            window.innerWidth = 700;
        }
```

```html
<button onclick="resize()">resize</button>
```

But it is not working. Is it possible to resize browser using JavaScript or jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I resize the browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022787/can-i-resize-the-browser-window)

Comment: Some browser vendors removed that feature from their JavaScript implementations, right around the time of the rick-roll, when they also removed the constant `alert()`'s popping up non-stop to prevent you from closing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this . Use resizeTo()

```js
function resize() {
           window.resizeTo(250,250); //window.resizeTo(width,height);
        }
```

```html
<button onclick="resize()">resize</button>
```

Comment: This is working fine in IE11. But not working for other browsers like chrome and firefox.

Comment: Most of the modern browsers don't allow it I guess. You can try opening a new window and then resize it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, although - as you may know - it is not particularly recommended that this is done. It is detrimental to user experience, usually.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeScreenSize() {        
        window.resizeTo(screen.width-300,screen.height-500)   
    }
</script>

<body onload="changeScreenSize()">
```

This also might work:

```
window.resizeTo( width, height );
```

But as far as I understand it, there is NOT a way to resize the browser in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with window's size provided if it is created using window.open(). Please refer this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo, especially the **NOTE:** section.