# Resizing window size in angular 2

Tags: angular

I know that there are ways to get the width and height of the browser window. But what If I want to programmatically change the width or height. How do I do that?
I have assigned a value in `window.innerWidth=500` and `window.innerHeight = 500`. But that does not help. What to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048802/6555572

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with plain javascript function [resizeTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) as suggested already in comments using:

```
(<any>window).resizeTo(width, height);
```