# Set NodeJS console default window size

Tags: node.js

I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere, but is there a way to set a default window size for node.exe? Ideally I'd like my window to always start 1000x600. I'm not seeing a javascript command to do this, and I'm not seeing a config file in the file tree either.

EDIT: I am asking how to ***SET*** the window size. I don't care what value it had before.

Comment: No. My question asks if you can SET the window size. Not read it.

Comment: I do not think this is possible with nodejs. One way to do that is set the window size with the client side javascript, but to do that read this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022787/can-i-resize-the-browser-window