# How to trigger resize event in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to trigger resize event in my angular application but it is not working. Getting error like

> Property 'initUIEvent' does not exist on type 'UIEvent'. Did you mean
> 'initEvent'?

I do not know why I am getting this error. How to resolve this issue?

app.component.ts:

```
  trigger() {
     if (typeof Event === 'function') {
     window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  } else {
  var resizeEvent = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents');
  resizeEvent.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0);
  window.dispatchEvent(resizeEvent);
  }
 }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnx4mq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: What browser are you using? Your example pen works perfectly fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and latest IE.

Comment: @tao: Checking in all browser..like chrome, firefox, Safari, IE

Comment: You seem to have misread my question: it should read: *"What browser are you using **when you get the error***?"

Comment: They told you @tao

Comment: @tao: else condition code not working in chrome firefox and IE

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need. Widely supported.

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
```

If you have objects that resize on the page and they're not inside the window resize event to perform their task this won't touch those elements.

Comment: window.onresize = () => {   } should contain your functions that'd update when resize occurs. Unfortunately forcing resize conflicts with requestAnimationFrame policies in cases like that. If you need to force resize don't call it in a timeout, that's improper.

Comment: Know when browser loses focus these timers don't update the way they would. This RAF will idle entire process down to 1 FPS, you can bypass it by it makes for very unresponsive coding practices. :)

Answer (score 0):

the easer way to subscribe to resize is using `fromEvent`of rxjs operators

```
fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(
  debounceTime(200)
).subscribe(() => {
  ...your code here...
})
```

You can use in a ngOnInit or in a function after click a button:

```
  tigger(){
    fromEvent(window, 'resize')
      .pipe(debounceTime(200))
      .subscribe(event => {
        console.log('size changed.', event);
      });

  }
  //or
  ngOnInit() {
    fromEvent(window, 'resize')
      .pipe(debounceTime(200))
      .subscribe(event => {
        console.log('size changed.', event);
      });
  }
```

Ah!, if you don't put in the app.component, don't forget unsubscribe
see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whkf2v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: I add a debounceTime to not execute "each time"

Comment: Not working : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-36mmmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Sansara, I forked your stackblitz and updated the answer. I hope this help you

Comment: Not working on onclick condition : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kepubb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Sansara, see that the actions that are executed are the instructions under "subscribe" -you can call a function inside this-

Comment: Not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s17xks?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: After you click the button, if you resize the navigator you get an alert. What do you want to say when you say "not working"? take account to refresh the navigation, because you don't destroy the subscription, so if you click two times the button, you has two alerts

Comment: Check this..Not working : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsmysp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Just if i click the button i want to trigger the resize event

Comment: if you want to change the size of the navigator, see this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022787/can-i-resize-the-browser-windowJust  The code I left it's only to **detect** when the user resize the navigator.