# How to resize Internet Explorer browser in Java

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to open an Internet Explorer window from Java code as below:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(folder + ":\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IEXPLORE.EXE  http://google.com/");
```

That works fine but my requirement is to open the window at a small size, for which I followed the link [How do you resize an IE browser window to 1024 x 768](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030/how-do-you-resize-an-ie-browser-window-to-1024-x-768). But I don't know how I can use the JavaScript solution from Java code.

I tried passing it on the command line:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(folder + ":\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IEXPLORE.EXE javascript:resizeTo(1024,768); http://google.com/");
```

But it is not working. Please suggest if you have any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you try `\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore javascript:resizeTo(1024,768); http://google.com/` on a command line, you will find it does not do what you are expecting.

iexplore does not seem to respect the javascript protocol properly in this scenario.

When i tried, it seems to open the save file dialog rather than running the code. I suggest this is the problem you need to workaround.

I have not investigated further, but you might try a custom protocol handler or some other way of having iexplore run the js, whether from the CLI or otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> javascript:resizeTo(1024,768); vbscript:resizeto(1024,768)
> ```
>
> Will work in IE7, But consider using something like
>
> ```
> javascript:moveTo(0,0);resizeTo(1024,768);
> ```
>
> because IE7 doesn't allow the window to "resize" beyond the screen borders. If you work on a
>   1024,768 desktop, this is what happens...
>
> Firefox: 1024x768 Window, going behind the taskbar. If you drop the
>   moveTo part, the top left corner of the window won't change
>   position.(You still get a 1024x768 window) IE7: As close as possible
>   to the requested size without obscuring the taskbar or allowing any
>   part of the window to lie beyond the screen borders. safari: As close
>   as possible to the requested size without obscuring the taskbar or
>   allowing any part of the window to lie beyond the screen borders, but
>   you can ommit the moveTo part. Safari will move the top left corner of
>   the window for you. Opera: Nothing happens. Chrome: Nothing happens.

This quote is from: Tolle you can find his post here:
[How do you resize an IE browser window to 1024 x 768](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030/how-do-you-resize-an-ie-browser-window-to-1024-x-768?lq=1)

Hopefully this is help full to you!

Comment: As in my question i have already mentioned that i have followed the same link to which you have preferred , but my problem is that how i integrate this `javascript:resizeTo(1024,768);`  in my java code .

Comment: @AjeetVarma Well, So stupid from me! I apologize, will not happen again. Good luck with your search to the answer!